# Play video on laravel blade

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, html5-video

Trying to use the video player on the page.

```
    <video  src="{{URL::asset("/images/upload/$itemContent->file_name")}}" controls>
    </video>
```

The link is correct (the file is available in the source code of the page). In the case of mp4 only audio.

Comment: you are incorrect added video sources. try <video controls>
  <source src="{{$url}}" type="video/mp4(or whatever you need)"></video>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="{{URL::asset("/images/upload/$itemContent->file_name")}}" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp